# Linker Error: Undefined symbols _gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type

Tags: c, gstreamer

I've got a weird issue with compiling a gstreamer file. I'm executing:

```
gcc file-name.c -o file-name \
    `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-plugins-bad-1.0 gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0` \
    -v && ./file-name
```

There is a definition in the file `GST_TYPE_WEBRTC_SESSION_DESCRIPTION` which exists within (part of `gstreamer-plugins-bad-1.0`:

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gst-plugins-bad/1.20.3_1/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/webrtc/rtcsessiondescription.h`

Lines of interest in the header are:

```
#define GST_TYPE_WEBRTC_SESSION_DESCRIPTION (gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type())
GST_WEBRTC_API
GType gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type(void);
```

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type", referenced from:
      _on_offer_created in simple-webrtc-example-1deda3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm guessing it can't find `gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type` but I can't reason as to why. Can someone with more C experience shed some light on this?

The file itself is here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/gst-libs/gst/webrtc/rtcsessiondescription.h

---

I've done nothing fancy but `brew install` these libs and reference `GST_TYPE_WEBRTC_SESSION_DESCRIPTION` from them.

EDIT

Got it working by replacing `gstreamer-plugins-bad-1.0` with `gstreamer-webrtc-1.0`

```
gcc simple-webrtc-example.c -o simple-webrtc-example `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-webrtc-1.0 gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0` && ./simple-webrtc-example
```

Comment: `type` in that case is the type of SDP message stored. I'm not sure its related?

Comment: Solved. Updated my question.